# Insert into .dbf with Conditional Subquery on VFPOLEDB from C#

Tags: c#, sql, oledb, visual-foxpro, dbf

I ´ve the challenge to implement a query to insert into a dbf. I am working on C#. If I am using a query in a Sql works fine but no on VFPOLEDB. The things is that I have no idea to makes it work.

Ok. This is what I have implement to give a try to see if works.
My query:

```
    string query = "INSERT INTO relojj (id, numdoc, fecha, maquina, tipo, veces, sucursal,                     transf, forma, audito, newfld ) " +
                                "VALUES (@id,@numdoc,@fecha,@maquina,@sucursal," +
                                "IIF((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM relojj WHERE numdoc=@numdoc and fecha=@fecha)%2=0 , 'E', 'S')," +
                                "(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM relojj WHERE numdoc=@numdoc and fecha=@fecha)," +
                                "@sucursal,@transf,@forma,@audito,@newfld)";
```

Then I have instance a command to insert those values into the dbf

```
    command.Parameters.Add("id", OleDbType.VarChar, 5).Value = "1";
    command.Parameters.Add("numdoc", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = 1;      
    command.Parameters.Add("fecha", OleDbType.Date).Value = fecha;
    command.Parameters.Add("maquina", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "Reloj Rio Grande";
    //command.Parameters.Add("tipo", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "tipo";
    //command.Parameters.Add("veces", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = 1;
   command.Parameters.Add("sucursal", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "sucursal";
   command.Parameters.Add("transf", OleDbType.Date).Value = transf;
   command.Parameters.Add("forma", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "R";
   command.Parameters.Add("audito", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "Alta Automatica";
   command.Parameters.Add("newfld", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "newfld";
```

But once I tried it it show me an error let me know that I have Sintaxis Error. If I have a normal query runs ok but Iff or even When case, no working.
any idea.
Thanks

Comment: `show me an error` what error? A syntax error means the SQL query is wrong. Can you execute the SQL query with hard-coded values at all?

Comment: `in a Sql works fine` if you mean SQL Server, the query is hard to read and maintain and won't work in other databases. Each database has its own functions, its own quirks and its own way of specifying parameters

Comment: This is the error 
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error.'
@PanagiotisKanavos what I mean is that this syntax will run fine on SQL sever, take into account the way IFF is implement. Other wise I can make querys to save in any var and Insert them on the query, but this is running on a Minimal API son I am trying to do all at once. Any help will be great

Comment: FoxPro isn't SQL Server and doesn't have the same functions. Find an administration tool or IDE for FoxPro and try to execute your queries *before* you use them in code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. This is what I try on Visual Fox and works. You were right. No even on Fox works my IIF (SELCET ....) so I have to change it.
     SELECT COUNT(id) as cant FROM relojj WHERE numdoc=24186365 and TTOD(fecha)=CTOD("05/09/2023") INTO CURSOR veces

INSERT INTO relojj (id, numdoc, fecha, maquina, tipo, veces, sucursal, transf, forma, audito, newfld ) ;
 VALUES ("25",24186365,DATETIME(),"Mi PC",IIF(MOD(veces.cant,2)=0, 'E', 'S'),veces.cant+1,"0028",DATETIME(),"R","PEPE"," ")
So now that I know I will try to do it  on c#

Comment: When asking a question related to VFP, try to avoid using SQL tag.

Comment: @CetinBasoz. Thank for your advise. I will. I still learning from you guys. regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VFPOLEDB is an OLEDB provider and it is not SQL server. It doesn't support named parameters, and that is the reason you are getting a syntax error. You need to replace all those named parameters with positional arguments (all parameters statring with @ to ?). Since it doesn't support named parameters but positional only, you need to supply the same parameter like @numdoc more than once and you need to do that in order (? are matched by their positions). Your query as is a little confusing and doesn't look right for SQL server or another backend either (you are inserting sucursal for tipo? as an example), assuming those were typos, your query would look like (instead of string concatenation, verbatim strings are better for readability):

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO relojj 
        (id, numdoc, fecha, maquina, tipo, veces, 
        sucursal, transf, forma, audito, newfld )
        VALUES 
        (?,?,?,?,?,?
        IIF((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM relojj WHERE numdoc=? and fecha=?)%2=0 , 'E', 'S'),
        (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM relojj WHERE numdoc=? and fecha=?),
        ?,?,?,?,?)";
                           

command.Parameters.Add("id", OleDbType.VarChar, 5).Value = "1";
command.Parameters.Add("numdoc", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = 1;
command.Parameters.Add("fecha", OleDbType.Date).Value = fecha;
command.Parameters.Add("maquina", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "Reloj Rio Grande";
command.Parameters.Add("tipo", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "tipo";
command.Parameters.Add("veces", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = 1;

command.Parameters.Add("numdoc1", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = 1;
command.Parameters.Add("fecha1", OleDbType.Date).Value = fecha;

command.Parameters.Add("numdoc2", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = 1;
command.Parameters.Add("fecha2", OleDbType.Date).Value = fecha;

command.Parameters.Add("sucursal", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "sucursal";
command.Parameters.Add("transf", OleDbType.Date).Value = transf;
command.Parameters.Add("forma", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "R";
command.Parameters.Add("audito", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "Alta Automatica";
command.Parameters.Add("newfld", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "newfld";
```

EDIT: Note that parameter names are only for you the developer, all parameters are matched by their order of position.

EDIT2: Correction of the syntax, doesn't mean that this would run in VFP. You have constructs like:

```
IIF(select ...) % 2 = 0
```

That kind of queries do not work in VFP. To workaround, you would do those two select separately and use the results in your insert. Thus it becomes:

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO relojj 
        (id, numdoc, fecha, maquina, tipo, veces, 
        sucursal, transf, forma, audito, newfld )
        VALUES 
        (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                           

    var cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM relojj WHERE numdoc=? and fecha=?", < your connection >);
cmd1.Parameters.Add("numdoc", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = 1;
cmd1.Parameters.Add("fecha", OleDbType.Date).Value = fecha;
    var cnt = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());


command.Parameters.Add("id", OleDbType.VarChar, 5).Value = "1";
command.Parameters.Add("numdoc", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = 1;
command.Parameters.Add("fecha", OleDbType.Date).Value = fecha;
command.Parameters.Add("maquina", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "Reloj Rio Grande";
command.Parameters.Add("tipo", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = cnt%2 == 0?"E":"S";
command.Parameters.Add("veces", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = cnt;
command.Parameters.Add("sucursal", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "sucursal";
command.Parameters.Add("transf", OleDbType.Date).Value = transf;
command.Parameters.Add("forma", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "R";
command.Parameters.Add("audito", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "Alta Automatica";
command.Parameters.Add("newfld", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "newfld";
```

Comment: Hi @CetinBasoz, After all I tried to run th same query on VFP and I see the order error with the param. And I see that IIF(Select....) is no the right way to do it. So I had to do it in another query and save in a var to do IIF(var ....).
Thank u.
Once I finish I upload the code.